# How to Divorce my wife

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I kill my wife? I married a assassin girl thing and if I attack her in my house will she attack back? Or will my housecarl then attack me? I'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

Your wife can be killed, tho not sure if she will attack back. I am not sure if the housecarl will "defend" her, so you could for safety just lead the housecarl into another room, close the door, then go and knock your wife out. Alternative is to order your housecarl to attack your wife first, beware they MIGHT not be able to do that, as they then will say "can not do that".

Whatever the case, both your wife and the housecarl are no match of you are decently geared. Your wife will at least not carry anything more than maybe an iron dagger. Your housecarl, if you've not armored him\her up, they will usually carry a iron shield and sword, meaning they won't do much damage. Housecarl usually seem to have high healthpool, tho (they don't die so easily).

You can not divorce your wife\husband, you can only kill them. You can't re-marry either, so if you wanna divorce to change wife\husband, you're out of luck. There might be a mod that let you do it, but I am certain you can't without.

Comment: Man, this question/answer/game mechanic cracked me up. For a second I thought I was on Stack Overflow.